# Comparación lógica entre substrings

Tags: java, condiciones, comparaciones

La aplicación marca error en la comparación, el programa es para calcular el CURP de una persona, por lo que debo escanear el primer apellido de la persona para encontrar la primera vocal inmediata a la primera letra del apellido

```
String name, fecha, n1,n2,n3,n4,vocal,v1,v2,v3, f1,f2,f3, A="A",E="E",I="I",O="O",U="U";
char[] curp=new char[13];
int sexo,edo,i,x=1,y=2;
//OBTENCIÓN DE DATOS
name=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Por favor ingrese su nombre completo comenzando por apellidos","CURP", 3 );
name=name.toUpperCase(); //CONVERSIÓN A MAYÚSCULAS
fecha=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Por favor ingrese su fehca de nacimiento en formato dd-mm-yyyy","CURP", 3 );
sexo=JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Por favor seleccione su sexo","CURP" , JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
3,null,new Object[] {"Hombre", "Mujer", "Cancel"},"Cancel");
edo=JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Por favor seleccione su entidad de nacimiento","CURP" , JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
3,null,new Object[] {"CDMX"/*DF*/, "Edo. Mex"/*MC*/, "Nuevo León"/*NL*/},"CDMX");
//SEPARACIÓN DE LOS STRING "name" Y "fecha" EN SUBSTRINGS 
String[] n=name.split(" ");     String[] f=fecha.split("-");
n1 = n[0];                          f1 = f[0];
n2 = n[1];                          f2 = f[1];
n3 = n[2];                          f3 = f[2];
n4 = n[3];                          
//ESCANEO DE LA PRIMERA VOCAL EL PRIMER APELLIDO
vocal=n1.substring(x,y); //PRIMERO ELEGIMOS DELIBERADAMENTE LA SEGUNDA LETRA
    int j = name.length();//PARA SABER SI ES DIFERENTE DE "A","E","I","O","U"
for(i=0;i==j;i++)
    {
        if( (n1.substring(x,y) )!=(A||E||I||O||U) )     ***ERROR EN ESTA LÍNEA***
        {x=x++; y=y++;}
        }
```

El error es `bad operand types for binary operator "||"`
Pero al ser boolean el retorno del If, debería funcionar :c

Comment: Ese operador se usa así ``if(!n1.substring(x, y).equals(A) || !n1.substring(x, y).equals(E))``

Comment: Los strings se comparan con equals, no con el operador lógico `!=`. Sugiero que revises cómo funcionan los String en Java. Ahora bien, qué se supone que debería obtenerse de hacer `A || E` ?

Comment: Antes que nada, una disculpa, soy muy nuevo no sólo en java si no en todo lo que la programación abarca.
Respondiendo a tu pregunta, si la letra n1.substring(x=1,y=2) es diferente a una e las vocales (A,E,I,O,U), se suma 1 tanto a la variable x, como a y para que comparen la siguiente letra y si es vocal, entonces esa se guarda en la variable vocal.

Comment: Estás leyendo `si el substring es diferente de (A o E o I o O o U)` y realmente está pasando que `si la instancia de String con el substring no es igual a (comparación lógica entre unos String A, E, I, O, U)` y eso no tiene sentido; estás comparando lógicamente unas cadenas de caracteres. Revisa el comentario de JFrame y lee sobre operadores en Java.